# ComboBox not showing in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want a `ComboBox` in my `DatagridView` but I got a problem.

I already google it but I can't find a suitable solution to my problem.

**This is my code in creating ComboBox:**

```
Dim comboBoxCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
comboBoxCell.Items.Add("ACT")
comboBoxCell.Items.Add("CAN")
comboBoxCell.Items.Add("PCAN")
```

**And this code if for calling the ComboBox:**

```
dgTitleList("sNewValue", dgTitleList.RowCount - 1).Value = comboBoxCell
```

The `sNewValue` is the name of the `column` in `Datagridview` and `dgTitleList` is the name of `DatagridView`.

**And here's the result:**

[image: This is the result]

I've tried everything on this.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Define a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.  Add it to the Columns collection.

Comment: Just as if you simply created a control in code without adding it to your form would not display the control in the form, so creating a column in code and not adding it to the grid means that it won't display in the grid.  How could it?  What if you had more than one grid?  Should it somehow magically know which grid to become part of?  I recommend that you create the column in the designer rather than in code.  To learn how to do that, check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476) out.